# Bash. Create array comma separated

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have following bash script:

```
declare -a nameserver=()
for ((n=1; n<=5; n++))
do
        read -p 'Enter DNS'$n' ? : ' dns
        if [ ! -z "$dns" ]
        then
                nameserver+=$dns
        else
                break
        fi
done
echo ${nameserver}
```

Output shows dns1dns2dns2

How to echo array whit comma separated values? Example : dns1, dns2, dns3

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that though you declare `nameserver` as an array, you're creating just a single string; you have to use `nameserver+=("$dns")` to append array elements.

Comment: The question has been closed while I've wrote my answer so I'll leave it here.
You've created an array 'nameserver' with this `declare -a nameserver=()` but in the loop you are appending 
not the array(not adding new items to an array) but appending just the first item of it(${nameserver[0]}) 
which is correspond with the variable `$nameserver`. 
This code: `nameserver+=$dns` append new value of `$dns` var into `$nameserver` var. 
That is why you've got 'dns1dns2dns2' in the end.

Comment: To append an array(add new items) you have to use this code: `nameserver+=("$dns")` as Jetchisel suggested. 
Or use your counter($n) and fill your array like this: `nameserver[$n]="$dns"`. 
Then you can use `printf` for pretty print the desired output, like so:
`printf '%s, ' "${nameserver[@]}"`

But if you need only the CSV, then a var is enough, append it like so:
`nameserver+="$dns, "`, then echo like this: `echo ${nameserver%, }` to drop the last ', '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but you can try an adjustment from your code.

```
declare -a nameserver=()
for ((n=1; n<=5; n++))
do
        read -p 'Enter DNS'$n' ? : ' dns
        if [ ! -z "$dns" ]
        then
                nameserver+=("$dns")
        else
                break
        fi
done
(IFS=,;printf '%s' "${nameserver[*]}")
```

---

A space separated with a comma.

```
printf -v output '%s' "${nameserver[*]/%/,}"
```

---

Remove the trailing comma.

```
echo "${output%,*}"
```

---

Although technically the `$*` same with `"${nameserver[*]}"` is not an array anymore, it is just a single string. So what you're asking for is a bit weird, unless you're trying to create a csv format or a python array.

---

Instead of negating the `-z`, just use `-n` without the bang `!` e.g.

```
[ -n "$dns" ]
```

---

`nameserver` is declared as and array but you're assigning a variable `nameserver+=` an array needs a `( )`.